# Trying to overwrite Bootstrap4 checkbox style

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate this custom checkbox `codepen`https://codepen.io/zFunx/pen/dWbevd?editors=0100

But for the rest of my project i use bootstrap4 and it overwrites my costom checkbox somehow.

Here is my test `My test`https://codepen.io/GitMorin/pen/aEXrJq

As you can see I have added a .myCheckbox class to the input compare to the working example. I got a bit stuck of how I can overwrite bootstrap to the cosutm checkboxes.

Does anyone have any advice? Much appreciated

Comment: You need to make sure that your css selectors are more specific than the Bootstrap ones. See for example the MDN page on CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Your `<input>` elements do indeed apply your styles; your selectors have higher specificity than those of Bootstrap. What *exactly* is the problem? What **should** be happening, and how does your current code differ from that?

Comment: The checkmark should be white and in the centre of the checkbox. Mine is green and is hanging on the side. If I remove the bootstrap4 cdn it works. I have added the class class="myCheckbox" to make it more specific and override bootstrap, but that did not appear to have helped.

Comment: @geogrow easy fix would be to add ``!important`` after every style value. (This is bad practice, but usefull for a hotfix)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the following CSS. This might be your correct answer. This is behaving differently from other because of font-family and some other CSS related things.

```
input.myCheckbox[type=checkbox] + label:before {
    content: "\2714";
    border: 0.1em solid #000;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: transparent;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

Comment: That did indeed placed the checkmark in the centre of the checkbox. The checkmark itself is still green though. Interestingly the checkmark is white if I open the codepen on my Android phone, but in chrome and IE its green.
I am trying to learn how to make custom checkboxes, but maybe I should try another approach.

Comment: @geogrow Is it solve your problem? For browser issue, you have to check every browser and update accordingly. If this solves your problem please mark as accepted.